# Firebase chat app (improve UX using CoreData????)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, firebase

I am currently working on a chat app using Firebase. Firebase Offline Capabilities works great. Currently I have no knowledge In CoreData, but I am starting to learn. The way my app works, is like this:

you write a message -> it goes to firebase -> updates the collection View

The problem I am having, is sometimes I have a very slow connection, So the message takes a while to go to the collection view.

I want to make my app work like this:

write a message -> Go to collectionView First -> Then Go to firebase -> update label under message with "Sent"

Right now when I do that, the message goes to collectionView then firebase is triggered and it duplicates the message.

and If I use logic to stop firebase from duplication the message is lost, when I leave the view.

Right Now, I feel like the only solution to my problem is to do it like this:

send a message -> put in coreData -> put in collectionView -> put in firebase -> Observe Messages from firebase -> if message is already inside coreData do not duplicate.

so the question is, is there an easier way to do this with/without coredata?

and If I have to use coredata, what should I really be focusing on, I read somewhere that I would need two contexts, a parent and a child, one works on the main queue with the UI, and the other works in the background to get the messages from firebase, am I on the right track? (sorry for the long inexperienced question)

Answer (score -2):

Instead of Core Data, you can just store messages to a Singleton as an array. 
and in my case, it works very fast and no problem with delaying with Firebase Chat. 
I believe you must be using the JSQMessagesViewController for the chat view.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend storing messages in an array in memory - then you have to manually manage the length of that array and either drop off, cache, or otherwise store the messages into a more permanent database. CoreData, while challenging to implement, is designed for things like this.

Comment: then try this way. you just show only 10 messages in the chat view. and storing messages in memory doesn't take such a huge memory at all. you just store your images, videos on the device, other information is just a text, and it doesn't need such a huge amount of memory. If it doesn't fit to your requirement, you can use CoreData as well. CoreData is not difficult to use.

Comment: That's a _question_ not an answer – and is certainly not a solution ;)

Comment: again. try this way. you just show only 10 messages in the chat view. and storing messages in memory doesn't take such a huge memory at all. you just store your images, videos on the device, other information is just a text, and it doesn't need such a huge amount of memory. If it doesn't fit to your requirement, you can use CoreData as well. CoreData is not difficult to use.

Comment: That's my point. You can easily display _what's shown on the screen_ in an array, but what happens when someone scrolls back or forward? You have to then manually calculate which messages to show and it becomes a huge burden of juggling which messages are visible in the array, but surpass 100 messages, and it's (imo) not worth fighting with arrays.

Comment: you're right. In that case, CoreData will be a good choice. Try using CoreData, it's not difficult.